# How to create a custom view for iOS on Flutter app

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I want to be able to create a custom screen (viewController and storyboard) for iOS when a button is pressed.

I have a method channel:

```
static const channel = const MethodChannel('myChannel');
```

I have a function in the main.dart file of the flutter app:

```
Future <Null> launchCustomView() async {
   if(Platform.isIOS) {
      try {
        await channel.invokeMethod('startCustomView');
      } on PlatformException {}
   }
}
```

which I call under a specific condition (when a RaisedButton is pressed).
In the AppDelegate.swift I have this:

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)


    var controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController;
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel.init(name: "myChannel", binaryMessenger: controller);

    channel.setMethodCallHandler({(call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
        if ("startCustomView" == call.method) {
            // Load a new view
        } else {
            result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented);
        }
    });
```

If I have a storyboard and a viewcontroller, how would I get these to be displayed instead of the flutter/dart widgets?

Comment: Why do you want to implement your view in swift instead of dart?

Comment: I need to integrate Twilio Video Calling